# Proof that principal branch of logarithm is continuous function

Tags: complex-analysis

I tried to do an exercise in my book, please could someone tell me if my thoughts are correct?

Exercise: Prove that $\arg : \mathbb C_- \to \mathbb C$ is continuous and conclude that the principal branch of the logarithm is continuous on $\mathbb C_-$ (the complex numbers without the negative real axis).

My thoughts: I would say that since the lenght of a complex number has no influence on the argument it is enough to show that $\arg$ is continuous on the circle minus $-1$. If a point on the circle is given as $x + iy$ (with $x^2 + y^2 =1$) then $\sin \arg = {y \over x^2 + y^2} = y$ hence $\arg(x+iy) = \arcsin y$.

Now unfortunately, even though looking at a picture immediately makes it clear that $\arcsin$ is continuous, I do not know how to prove it rigourously. So:

> (1) Can someone explain to me how to prove that $\arcsin$ is
>   continuous?
>
> (2) Is there a better way to prove the claim?
>
> (3) Is what I did correct?

Comment: You need to be careful to exclude zero, too. Not clear if that is implicitly included in the "negative real axis."

Comment: You can use the fact that the complex plane without the negative axis (plus 0) is open in order to argue that you can put an open disc with an arbitrarily small radius $\epsilon$ anywhere on the unit circle except at $(-1,0)$.